# Deployment getting failed due to Time based workflow

Tags: deployment, time-dependent-workflow, git, github

I m getting below issue when deploying the workflow rules from the git to sandbox and also removed the all pending actions from the sandbox then re tried it again but no luck, same issue occuring even though there are not actions for pending.

Error : This workflow rule currently has pending actions in the workflow queue. To delete, please remove those pending actions.

[image]

Anyone facing similer issue?can anyone help us here

Comment: Did you try deactivating the workflow in the target org and deploy it?

Comment: no but i will try, small query i m deploying via git and in repository workflow status is active, so will work?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala tried but not worked

Comment: Can you check by using following 1. make sure the workflow rule is deactivated in the source org
2. add it to a new change set, then upload to the destination org. 
3. make sure the workflow rule is inactive in the destination org

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala i tried and its not working.